# Confused on pass-by-reference

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, pass-by-reference

Consider the below example where I am attempting to pass-by-reference in the C way:

```
// Function prototypes
void increment(unsigned* number);

int main()
{
    unsigned* thing;
    increment(thing);
    cout << *thing;
    return 0;
}

void increment(unsigned* number)
{
    number = (unsigned*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned));
    *number = 1;
}
```

I get a program crash at the line `cout << *thing`. Yes, I am using C++ here but I wanted to try out the C version of pass-by-reference because my main project is in C.

I fixed it by changing the code as follows:

```
// Function prototypes
void increment(unsigned** number);

int main()
{
    unsigned* thing;
    increment(&thing);
    cout << *thing;
    return 0;
}

void increment(unsigned** number)
{
    *number = (unsigned*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned));
    **number = 1;
}
```

And now it works and the output is 1, like I expected. However, I do not understand why. I'm a bit confused as to why layering an extra pointer on top solves my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Golden Rule: arguments are *always* passed by value.  You only updated the local copy of the pointer.  It did not propagate back to the caller, because it was passed by value, kaboom.  Note how in the working version you did not change the *number* argument.  You changed *number, like you should.

Comment: I am working on a C++ application that talks to embedded C, I think that's why it is confusing.

Comment: C does not support pass by reference.

Comment: VS-compiler accepts pass by reference with C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C doesn't have pass-by-reference. Except for arrays, all parameters are passed by value.

In your first version, you're passing the variable `thing` by value. In the `increment` function, it allocates memory and assigns that to the local variable `number`. But this has no effect on the caller's variable, because only its value was passed, not a reference to the variable. So `thing` is still uninitialized when `increment` returns, and indirecting through it results in undefined behavior.

If a function needs to modify a caller's variable, the caller has to pass a pointer to the variable, not just the value. That's what you did in the second version. Then the function can indirect through the pointer to update the variable.

This is essentially what's going on under the covers when you use references in C++. In C you have to code the extra level of indirection explicitly.

Comment: Ahhh wow, thank you! I am working on a C++ program on top of a C one, so this one took me a while to figure out. Appreciate your easy explanation.

Comment: "Except for arrays, all parameters are passed by value." All parameters are by value. It's not possible to have a parameter of array type.

Comment: @newacct You can't have a parameter of array type, but you can use an array as an argument, and it's not copied. Since it gets converted to a pointer, it acts much like pass by reference, because changes to the array in the function affect the caller's variable.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you were looking for was something like this:

```
void increment(unsigned* number);

int main()
{
    unsigned thing;
    increment(&thing);
    cout << thing;
    return 0;
}

void increment(unsigned* number)
{
    *number = 1;
}
```

In C, all function parameters are passed by value.  So you can't change a value in a function and expect to be reflected in the caller.  But if the value passed in is a pointer, you CAN change what it points to.  In this example, the address of `thing` is passed to `increment`.  Then in `increment`, `number` contains the address of `thing` in `main`.  So then you can change what `number` points to (i.e. `thing`), then when you return `thing` has been modified.

This differs slightly from your second example in that there's no dynamic memory allocation going on, which I believe is what you were aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

Saying to pass by reference in the context of your example means to pass a pointer to an object.

A pointer is itself an object as in your program

```
int main()
{
    unsigned* thing;
    //...
```

So to pass this object `thing` of type `unsigned*` by reference you have to pass a pointer to this object

```
void increment(unsigned** number);

int main()
{
    unsigned* thing;
    increment(&thing);
    //...
```

I think it will be more clear for you if to introduce a typedef. Imagine the following example

```
typedef unsigned* T;

void increment( T* number);

int main()
{
    T thing;
    increment( &thing );
    //...
```

I hope now it is more clear.:)

Answer (score 0):

The second way you posted is the correct way to do it. The reason the first way doesn't work is that you are trying to modify `number` when `number` has in fact been passed by value. So although you *have* in fact passed the variable `thing` to `increment` by reference, the *address* of `thing` has been passed to `increment` by value.