# Why do we feed an adress to scanf?

Tags: c, pointers

So in the following snippet, we ask the user to assign some value to our integer `x`.

```
   int x;
   scanf("%d", &x);
```

What I'm confused about is why we're saying "put the value of the input into the adress of x", instead of just "let x be equal to the value of the input"? What would be the problem with `scanf("%d", x)`?

Comment: I think the second part of [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32036129/3049655) will help you understand.

Comment: Because you're basically passing a parameter to a function. If you don't pass it by reference scanf() will be modifying its local copy.

Comment: What would be the problem if we said `scanf("%d", 5)?`

Comment: @n.m. Sir, in this case, another issue will arise, as `5` is not an _lvalue_, anyway. Just saying. :)

Comment: @n.m. Very concise :)

Comment: Because this isn't c++

Comment: @SouravGhosh You know about lvalues, then you should also know about the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, which kicks in right after you utter "but `x` is an lvalue".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to take a slightly different approach and try and make you answer the question for yourself.

Consider the following code (that won't compile but supposes that you only need to do as you suggest and call scanf("%d", x)):

```
int w = 5;
int x = 5;
int y = 5;
int z = 5;
scanf("%d", x);
```

When you make the call to scanf, scanf doesn't know that you have passed the value of x, all it knows is that you have given it a value of 5, just as if you had written the line scanf("%d", 5)

Assuming you were the programmer who was coding scanf, if you've been given the parameters "%d" and 5, which of the variables w, x, y or z would you update? How would you even know that the variables w, x, y, z exist? How would you know that there aren't any other variables in the code with the value of 5? How would you know that the value of 5 you have received actually came from the variable x?

Answer (score 7):

In C, parameters are passed by value. So if you use `x` as a parameter to `scanf`, it just gets a copy of the value of `x`, it doesn't get a reference to the actual variable `x`.

By passing a pointer, you're giving it the address of the memory that the `x` variable's value is stored in. That allows `scanf` to modify the value of `x` by storing into that memory.

Comment: "parameters are passed by value" except those pesky [arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11158906/2410359)

Comment: I can't win. A few weeks ago I posted that arrays are passed by reference, someone commented that they're not. They're converted to pointers and the pointer is passed by value.

Comment: Hmmm.  "Array expressions and function designators as arguments were converted to pointers before the call" §6.9.1 10 so the function is called with pointers (which supports your "passed by value").  With that, an array cannot be passed to a function, the array argument being converted to a pointer first.  Or in another perspective, the calling code _does_ pass an array to a function.  The language then converts that array argument with a conversion as part of "On entry to the function" (same ref).  I shall ponder.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31687178/1491895 for the answer where someone complained when I said arrays are passed by reference.

Answer (score 3):

All function calls take their arguments by value. Passing `x` would just give `scanf` a copy of `x`, and it still wouldn't have access to *our* `x`.

Taking the address of a variable produces a pointer, which when copied, still points to the same variable. Thus `scanf` can dereference its copy of the pointer and gain access to `x`.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: because you have to. The specification of `scanf` says that for the format specifier `%d` it expects the corresponding argument to have the type `int *`, which means `&x`, not `x`.

C doesn't have pass-by-reference. `scanf` is a function like any other and when you pass a variable to it, you don't pass the variable itself, but its value. So when you call `scanf("%d", x);` you give it the (uninitialized) value of `x`, which is useless to `scanf`. When you pass the address of `x`, `scanf` can put the value it scanned into `x` by dereferencing it.

As n.m. commented, calling `scanf("%d", x);` is (somewhat) equivalent to calling `scanf("%d", 5);` (or more accurately: `scanf("%d", <garbage>);`). It can't assign to a constant, or an ordinary number, but it can assign to the place that a (valid) address points to.